# how can a write a 2-d array without any imports?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix, 2d

Anyone know how to write a 2d array?

The result:

```
[[0,1,0]

[0,2,0]

[0,3,0]]
```

And with no imports or any library:

```
a=[]
for y in range (3):
    row=[]
    for x in range (3):
        row.append(0)
        a.append(row)
```

I've come up this far.

**The answer should contain these codes you can add and edit but you can't remove.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned. **The answer should contain these codes you can add and edit but you can't remove**

**Code:**

```
a=[]
for i in range(1,4):
    tmp=[]
    for j in range(3):
        if j!=1:
            tmp.append(0)
        elif j==1:
            tmp.append(i)
    a.append(tmp)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Naively, you could write this 2D array as a literal:

```py
arr = [[0,1,0], [0,2,0], [0,3,0]]
```

but I guess this isn't what you meant. You could also use list comprehensions to build it from a range:

```py
arr = [[0, i + 1, 0] for i in range(3)]
```